# APT unable to update after release upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Ubuntu 16.04LTS -> 18.04LTS upgrade failure

Yes it was a long in the tooth install. But it finally got a release upgrade.  Since then I haven't been able to get apt to install anything much looking for dosemu but has no targets, and update spews errors about InRelease not containing bionic.

W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository                                          'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component '

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal bionic main restricted universe

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal bionic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal bionic partner
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal bionic main # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe
```

The google-fu gives all sorts of strange answers, but nothing I can find fixes this issue.

Regards, A

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`? You'll probably need to make some edits in there.

Comment: There should not be distribution 'focal' listed because you only upgraded to bionic.

Comment: Added sources.list

Comment: What does `lsb_release -r` tell?

Comment: lsb_release -r = 18.04

Comment: Did you try to upgrade to Focal as some point? I think you have to manually edit the file and possibly some files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to not contain words `focal` or `focal-*`, but contain respective `bionic` and `bionic-*`, instead. (only one at a line)

Comment: no idea what Focal is... pretty sure whats in there are defaults, I'm beginning to understand the error better.. its focal missing from bionic, not bionic itself that's missing?

Comment: focal is the codename for Ubuntu 20.04. Like bionic is the codename for 18.04 (and is given by `lsb_release -cs`) In 20.04 I have a word starting by focal in every deb line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and no bionic there. Not all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` might have one of those words, though. See `man 5 sources.list` for reference.

Comment: if you'd like to post your first question phrased as an answer, I'll give you the bickies. I better go back and put bionic in there, but removing focal got me over the speed hump. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and possibly some files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to not contain words `focal` or `focal-*`, but contain respective `bionic` and `bionic-*`, instead. (Only one of them per line.)